# mysql 8 pivot query should return a non null value

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions, mysql-8.0

I would like the following pivot query to show value 0 instead of null,

```
SELECT 
    pi.employeeId,
    pi.Id,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN pi.category = 'Repayment' THEN pi.value
        WHEN isnull(pi.category) = 1 then 0
        -- ELSE 0
    END) as 'Repayment',
     MAX(CASE
        WHEN pi.category = 'Salary' THEN pi.value
        ELSE 0
    END) as 'Salary',
     MAX(CASE
        WHEN pi.category = 'Allowance' THEN pi.value
        ELSE 0
    END) as 'Allowance'
FROM
   payData pi
GROUP BY pi.employeeId , pi.Id ;
```

Output for the above is,

```
employeeId     Id      Repayment    Salary  Allowance
  121          2           2000     15000     1000
  122          2           null     20000     2000
```

Employee id 122 does not have a *Repayment* value so the desired output is,

```
employeeId     Id      Repayment    Salary  Allowance
    121        2         2000       15000     1000
    122        2           0        20000     2000
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=760720a8c4acf3e7a3d8f6a7ab9cc965)

Comment: It's nice of you to provide a fiddle. But the question should be complete without external references which may disappear over time. Please include the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements in the question itself. A fiddle is a nice bonus then.

Comment: Why have you commented out `-- ELSE 0`? Am I missing something? If you uncomment that, it'll give you what you want. (You can remove `WHEN isnull(pi.category) = 1 then 0` though)

Comment: See about COALESCE()

Comment: @stickybit It is the strangest thing, if i do uncomment  -- else 0 the advance repayment category is not showing on mysql developer. Nothing to do with the tool I know, but I am guessing something to do with the data. I am trying to find out what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for the second branch of the repayment `case`. If you want `0` when the category is not available, just `else 0`:

```
SELECT 
    employeeId,
    Id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'Repayment' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as Repayment,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'Salary'    THEN value ELSE 0 END) as Salary,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'Allowance' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as Allowance
FROM payData pi
GROUP BY employeeId, Id;
```

Notes:

- Don't use single quotes for identifiers! They should be used for literal strings only, as specified in ANSI SQL and supported in all databases.
- You have a mono-table query, so prefixing all column names is not mandatory